# Xamarin draw image on cameraview when using a barcode scanner

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, camera, barcode

Currently learning to use Xamarin and Android and i have a small question.
I am making a demo app that scans a barcode and after this it has to show a figure on the cameraview. So they both use the cameraview.

My idea was to first scan the barcode and depending on the barcode show a certain figure on the cameraview.

I'm trying to get this to work in Android first in Xamarin before doing this for other platforms like IOS and WP.

If i'm correct the barcode scanner and the code that is going to display a figure on the cameraview are both using the cameraview.

Is it possible to 'switch' from the barcode scanner to the figure viewer on the same cameraview?

Comment: What do you mean by "a certain figure"?

Comment: A certain figure like an arrow. That shows where the user has to go after scanning the barcode. I already saw in the documentation of the zxing barcode scanner on xamarin that you can create a custom overlay over the barcode scanner. Would that be an option?

Comment: Most of the time overlays are tricky. Won't a Toast message suffice?

Comment: I want it to look like an augmented reality thing. So a Toast would be too 'plain'. What is so tricky about using overlays?

Comment: You have to consider phone orientation and screen resolution. There's nothing bad about it, just make sure that small screened phones can handle it.